# Short story: Guy hired by woman to take her across post-apocalyptic Russia on a motorbike

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

The story centres around a guy in a Russia either dystopian or post global collapse of some kind like a depression.  He's riding some kind of electric motorbike or an [ojek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle_taxi) (a motorcycle taxi).

The young woman in question pays him in 'favours' (my inverted commas) to take her across Russia. At one point on one stop he gets into trouble and hitherto unknown fighting skill gets him out. They arrive at her destination and the budding romantic connection ends. It was all a transaction for her.

I recall it maybe being in a short story anthology, maybe translated to English from another language and publish sometime after the year 2000.

I'd like to examine the story for short film potential!

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)